ConsumesAttribute when Request.ContentType is null
I'm trying to restring an endpoint to process only certain content type using ConsumesAttribute. The problem is that this attribute does not consider null as a wrong content type. There is a comment in its source that I don't understand:
// Requests without a content type do not return a 415. It is a common pattern to place [Consumes] on
// a controller and have GET actions

I understand that this way want to allow GET methods for which ContentType is null but I'm getting null in POST method. The method has HttpPostAttribute. And the way I sent the request is
new HttpClient().PostAsync(url, new ByteArrayContent(new byte[] { 50, 51 }));

How can I fix this behavior or this is MS bug? Created an issue for it.

Have you check this link ? Is this answer you ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65813533/unable-to-get-asp-net-web-api-to-consume-an-unspecified-content-type?rq=2

@QingGuo Not really. Consumes really doesn't support null but it let such requests pass even though the specified type is different.
